# Hahn-Banach Thm for Normed Space.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed Space.
For $x \in X$ define
$J(x)=\{f \in X^ * : f(x)=\|x\|^2 , \|f\|=\|x\|\}$.
Prove that $J(x)$ is not the empty set.

Comment: Can you apply Hahn-Banach or is this something you have to do with more elementary tools?

Comment: As indicated by the title, the Hahn-Banach theorem is quite helpful in proving the assertion. Which forms of the Hahn-Banach theorem are you familiar with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hahn-Banach Thm for Normed Space](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243918/hahn-banach-thm-for-normed-space)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, the square missing in the other question is present here. But, @Bank, please add some context to the question. What have you to build on, what have you tried so far, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Define:
$$ f: \mathbb{R}x \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: ax \mapsto a\|x\|^2 $$
by the Hahn-Banach theorem there exists a $g \in X^*$ s.t. $\|g\| = \|f\|$ and $g = f$ on $\mathbb{R}x$. from this we get:
$$ \|g\| = \|f\| = \sup_{\|ax\| \leq 1} |f(x)| = \sup_{\|ax\| \leq 1} (|a|\|x\| \|x\|) = \|x\| $$
and
$$ g(x) = f(x) = f(1\cdot x) = 1\cdot \|x\|^2 = \|x\|^2 $$
thus we have proven that $g \in J(x)$.